# I need help understanding the Seforno's commentary on Shir HaShirim

Tags: commentaries, shir-hashirim

It is [Perek Hay Pasuk Yud Daled (5:12)](https://www.sefaria.org/Song_of_Songs.5.12?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en) and I can't understand it.

> עֵינָ֕יו כְּיוֹנִ֖ים עַל־אֲפִ֣יקֵי מָ֑יִם רֹֽחֲצוֹת֙ בֶּֽחָלָ֔ב
> יֹשְׁב֖וֹת עַל־מִלֵּֽאת׃

Here it is for anyone who wants to have a go.

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Perhaps try the notes on it here: https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=56109&st=&pgnum=340&hilite=

Comment: Can you clarify what you need help with? Do you need help understanding the Hebrew? Do you understand the Hebrew but need help with what he's really getting at? Is there some particular part of it you need help with, or all of it?

Answer (score 1):

So let's first translate the passuk:

> עֵינָ֕יו כְּיוֹנִ֖ים עַל־אֲפִ֣יקֵי מָ֑יִם רֹֽחֲצוֹת֙ בֶּֽחָלָ֔ב יֹשְׁב֖וֹת עַל־מִלֵּֽאת׃
>
> His eyes are like doves By watercourses, Bathed in milk, Set by a brimming pool.

The Seforno can be translated as follows (my translation), with the meaning outlined underneath, aided with @Loewian [link](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=56109&st=&pgnum=340&hilite=) detailed above:

> **like doves By watercourses** - To water from the salvation of worlds

To be understood as; if one walks in the ways of our forefathers they will merit the salvation of worlds, namely, a life in both this world and the next.

> **Bathed in milk** - The others in the milk of their deeds, who are at all times white and illuminating, to teach others.

To be understood; that when one practises such action (i.e. inspired by our forefathers) they will be 'bathed/washed' by their example, making themselves pure like (the white colour of) milk. These actions will thereby serve as a living example to others.

> **Set by a brimming pool** - That every purpose directed in their action was to complete themselves and others to the will of Hashem before Hashem. As they say, "Walk in My ways and be blameless/perfect".

To be understood; someone who acts in this correct manner is acting in the way G-d wants i.e. out of their great love for Hashem, they are seeking to show and teach others His ways.